# Android UI overlap Issue

Tags: android, xml, layout, webview

I currently have the layout as shown in the image, however (as can be seen in the xml) the WebView has a predefined layout_height value. I just want this exact look but a scalable version that does not need predefined values. So the bright blue section should have a height proportional to the button and should always be at the bottom, and the top bar with the URL EditText etc. should act in the same way. So the WebView should be able to scale to whatever size, to make sure all space is taken up.

[image: Layout Image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    style="?buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter URL"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" 
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions">
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.10" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="724dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:keepScreenOn="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you run this on devices/emulators of different sizes to see if it is correct? I would also suggest not using strict number values for width. For example with your EditText you could always set it to match_parent then add a margin for the other bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter URL"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:keepScreenOn="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ctl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer when the time limit is up.